# haystack django TypeError: 'ManyRelatedManager' object is not iterable

Tags: django, django-haystack

I got his strange error. even though i have put the `all()` call on the manytomany field
I still get this annoying error..

```
class GrantIndex():
    pilist = indexes.MultiValueField(model_attr='pilist',faceted=False) #then we do  iteration in template. if we set this as charField, we do prepare_pilist here!
    copilist = indexes.MultiValueField(model_attr='copilist',faceted=False)
    # content_auto=indexes.EdgeNgramField(model_attr='title')

    def get_updated_field(self):
        return "lastupdated"

    def get_model(self):
        return Grant

    def index_queryset(self,using=None):
        return self.get_model().objects.all()

    def prepare_pi(self, obj):      
        return "%s %s %s" %(obj.pi.first_name,obj.pi.last_name,obj.pi.professor.university,obj.pi.professor.academic.interests,obj.pi.professor.academic.publications)

    def prepare_pilist(self, obj):
        return [(p.firstname,p.lastname,p.email,p.university,p.academic.interests,p.academic.publications) for p in obj.pilist.all()]       


    def prepare_copilist(self, obj):
        return [(p.firstname,p.lastname,p.email,p.university,p.academic.interests,p.academic.publications) for p in obj.copilist.all()]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Always be sure to read the helpful descriptions that appear when selecting tags.

Answer (score 1):

You provided "model_attr" parameter, that prevents the "prepare_" routines from being used and at indexing time it'll go straight to 'pilist' and 'copilist.
Try removing them so you're code is used for indexing those fields.